# iterating over two vectors optimally

Tags: c++

i have two vectors each containing 50k objects representing data extracted from a log file. Each objects contains a timestamp, device name and a link name. One vector (downs) contains linkdown objects and the other vector (ups) contains linkup objects. i need to find link downtime for each device so i iterate over downs vector and check ups vector to see if (uptime > downtime && up_device== down_device && up_link == down _link). The inside loop starts at the top every time and this makes the downtime calculation slow down as it iterates through downs vector. Here is the loop:

```
for(link_iter p = downs.begin(); p!=downs.end(); ++p){
   for(link_iter q = ups.begin(); q!=ups.end(); ++q){
      if(q->time > p->time && q->dev == p-> dev && q->link == p->link){
        downtimes.push_back(downtime(q->time - p->time, q->dev, q->link));
        break;
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a way to advance q with p so q does not start at beginning of ups each time p increments? or is there a better approach? any help much appreciated !

Comment: This looks somewhat like C++. Could you please tag the programming language in your question?

Comment: Why not work this out as the log file is read in? Or at least only store the relevant data?

Comment: If you can sort the vectors first then you can make the links in a single pass. EDIT: Wait, maybe not -- why can there be multiple ups for a single down?

Comment: hi Cameron .. there is only a single up for each down and as up will occur after down i iterate over ups to find up time > down time and then push_back downtime.

Comment: @user: Ah, I didn't see the `break` :-) In which case, sorting them is the way to go, I think, because then you really can do it in one pass (similar to the merge part of a merge sort).

Comment: many thanks OMGtechy and Cameron ..i have modified as suggested. I read log file and if i get a down event i push_back into downs vector if however i get an up i reverse iterate over downs to find first matching device and link. i then create downtime and push_back into downtimes. many thanks again for help much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Posting OP comment:

*many thanks OMGtechy and Cameron ..i have modified as suggested. I read log file and if i get a down event i push_back into downs vector if however i get an up i reverse iterate over downs to find first matching device and link. i then create downtime and push_back into downtimes. many thanks again for help much appreciated !*